# Firefox Addon that recognize url and transform it to a Link

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, url

I'm looking for an Firefox addon that recognizes URLs on a webpage that are plain text and transform it to a real link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using [TextLink](http://piro.sakura.ne.jp/xul/_textlink.html.en) to do that for years, now.  It's an awesome little add-on.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [**URL Link**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/403).
It even translates textual mail addresses like someone@somewhere.com to www.somewhere.com. It's also highly configurable beyond what the proper offers at startup.

Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

[Linkification](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/190/). No silly double clicks, highlighting, or secret handshakes. Just regular clickable links, anywhere there's a URL.